# Selenium, como controlar a velocidade de execução do teste?

Tags: c#, testes, selenium-webdriver

Criando teste automatizados em C# usando Selenium, procuro saber como controlar a velocidade de execução do teste?

Comment: O que você tem até o momento?:

Comment: Até agora estou usando o Thread.Sleep pra esperar a page carregar antes de executar o próximo comando!

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou utilizar os comandos "setSpeed" ou "setTimeOut"?

Eles servem basicamente para controlar o tempo e a velocidade de execução dos scripts.

Segue link com maiores informações sobre: http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/use-of-setspeed-and-settimeout-commands.html

Answer (score 0):

Utilize esperas implícitas para controlar o fluxo de execução. Colocar sleeps não é uma boa prática pois onera muito a suíte de testes.

Com as esperas implícitas (aguardar até que um elemento seja exibido, esperar que a página seja carregada) não acontecerá de algum comando ser executado antes que o contexto esteja pronto.